# How to pass search criteria to controller using MVC AJAX PagedList

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I'm creating Advanced Search using MVC. What I mean by Advanced Search is user can do  combination search, for example, user can search by category = 'Child' and name contains 'A' or age <= 10. then the result is displayed using MVC PagedList.

I followed [UnobtrusiveAjax tutorial](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/tree/master/src/PagedList.Mvc4.Example/Views/UnobtrusiveAjax) based on example from [PagedList](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) source. I defined 2 files, Index.cshtml for View and _List.cshtml for PartialView. Index contains search criteria and a button to add more clause.

[image]

and _List contains table for displaying the result using AJAX

The problem is after I filtered by code for example contains 'A' and click search then navigate to page 2 the filter value is missing and it will display code which not contains 'A'. How to solve this problem?

ViewModel:

```
public class WorkflowStateListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> FilterField { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> FilterOperator { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> FilterString { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> FilterLogical { get; set; }
    public PagedList<WorkflowStateListDetailViewModel> WorkflowStateListDetailVM { get; set; }
    public int? Page { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Filter(WorkflowStateListViewModel workflowStateListVM, int? page)
{
    var workflowStatesQuery = from ws in db.WorkflowStates
                              where ws.RowStatus == true
                              select ws;
    if (workflowStateListVM.FilterField != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < workflowStateListVM.FilterField.Count(); i++)
        {
            workflowStatesQuery = DoFilter(workflowStatesQuery, workflowStateListVM.FilterField.ElementAt(i), workflowStateListVM.FilterOperator.ElementAt(i), workflowStateListVM.FilterString.ElementAt(i));
        }
    }

    workflowStatesQuery = workflowStatesQuery.OrderBy(ws => ws.Code);
    var workflowStateListDetailVM = from ws in workflowStatesQuery
                           select new WorkflowStateListDetailViewModel()
                           {
                               WorkflowStateID = ws.WorkflowStateID,
                               Code = ws.Code,
                               Name = ws.Name,
                               Level = ws.Level,
                               PIC = ws.PIC
                           };

    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return PartialView("_List", workflowStateListDetailVM.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 5));
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model ViewModels.WorkflowStateListViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Filter", "WorkflowState", 
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        UpdateTargetId = "workflowStateList"
    }, 
    new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    <div id="clauses">
    </div>
    <p>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownList("FilterField", new SelectList(Model.FilterField), new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownList("FilterOperator", new SelectList(Model.FilterOperator), new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FilterString, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <a href="#" id="addClause"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add new clause</a>
        </div>
    </p>

    <div id="workflowStateList">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_List", Model); }
    </div>
}
```

_List.cshtml

```
@model JOeBilling.ViewModels.WorkflowStateListViewModel
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                Code
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Level
            </th>
            <th>
                PIC
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.WorkflowStateListDetailVM)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "WorkflowState", new { id = item.WorkflowStateID })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "WorkflowState", new { id = item.WorkflowStateID })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "WorkflowState", new { id = item.WorkflowStateID })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Level)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PIC)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<br />

Page @(Model.WorkflowStateListDetailVM.PageCount < Model.WorkflowStateListDetailVM.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.WorkflowStateListDetailVM.PageNumber) of @Model.WorkflowStateListDetailVM.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model.WorkflowStateListDetailVM,
    page => Url.Action("Filter", new { page }),
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "workflowStateList" }))
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

**UPDATE 2**[image]

**UPDATE 3** Response tab

```
<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                <a href="/WorkflowState">Code</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="/WorkflowState">Name</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                Level
            </th>
            <th>
                PIC
            </th>
            <th>
                Created By
            </th>
            <th>
                Created Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Modified By
            </th>
            <th>
                Modified Date
            </th>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/WorkflowState/Edit/6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <a href="/WorkflowState/Details/6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>
                    <a href="/WorkflowState/Delete/6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    A06
                </td>
                <td>
                    Preparing Task Code
                </td>
                <td>
                    6
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    JKTWLA
                </td>
                <td>
                    28/04/2014 4:24:52 PM
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/WorkflowState/Edit/7"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <a href="/WorkflowState/Details/7"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>
                    <a href="/WorkflowState/Delete/7"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    A07
                </td>
                <td>
                    Closed
                </td>
                <td>
                    7
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    JKTWLA
                </td>
                <td>
                    28/04/2014 4:25:06 PM
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/WorkflowState/Edit/8"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <a href="/WorkflowState/Details/8"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>
                    <a href="/WorkflowState/Delete/8"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    C01
                </td>
                <td>
                    New Invoice
                </td>
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    JKTWLA
                </td>
                <td>
                    13/06/2014 10:49:00 AM
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>

    </table>
</div>
<br />

Page 2 of 2

<div class="pagination-container"><ul class="pagination"><li class="PagedList-skipToPrevious"><a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#workflowStateList" href="/WorkflowState/Filter?page=1" rel="prev">«</a></li><li><a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#workflowStateList" href="/WorkflowState/Filter?page=1">1</a></li><li class="active"><a>2</a></li></ul></div>
```

Comment: Please post the URL of the "UnobtrusiveAjax tutorial"

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner I've added the link, you can find the example from the source

Comment: Can you check if the request that gets Page 2 is realy an Ajax call via F12 - > Network

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner I think it is an ajax call, I have attached the picture to show you that is an ajax call

Comment: Please mark the link "Filter..." and check in Tab "Headers". There is a part with "Request Headers". There look for "XMLHttp"

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner Yes, there is only parameter page with values 2. How to pass WorkflowStateListViewModel to ajax call? I tried to pass through page => Url.Action("Filter", new { Model, page }) but it doesn't work

Comment: For the filter controlls to keep their state you should not have to pass their values to ajax. The Filter area should not be reloaded when the response-Html is written to the dom. For that the html - response should not contain the html for the filers. Can you show the response please?

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner I have updated the question to show the response

Comment: Step with the JS-Debugger into the JS function that replaces part of the DOM with the response. The replacement should not result in the filters being changed. It should be some code running after the replacement. Please check that.

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner How to step with the JS-Debugger into the JS function? I suspect that caused by IEnumerable<T>. I'm using IEnumerable<T> to show the FilterField, FilterOperator and FilterString. I updated the question to show you the ViewModel. What do you think, could I pass the values using IEnumerable<T>?